# Basic Match Making for Django and Python

Tags: python, django

So I have a model `Education` that is attached to the `UserProfile`. This model works as one assumes: `User` has gone to several schools in different areas.

What I'm trying to do is make a "score" depending on where users went. Basically, if they went to the same school, they get 10 points, same city, 5 points, same state, 2 points, and so on.

I've made some functions to attempt this but I have failed. Any advice?

```
info = {}
def edu_info(user1):
    user_1_cities = []
    user_1_schools = []
    user_1_state = []
    first_one = Education.objects.filter(owner=user1)
    for i in first_one:
        user_1_cities.append(str(i.city))
        user_1_schools.append(str(i.school))
        user_1_state.append(str(i.state))
        info[str(i.owner.username)] = {}
        info[str(i.owner.username)]['cities'] = user_1_cities
        info[str(i.owner.username)]['schools'] = user_1_schools
        info[str(i.owner.username)]['state'] = user_1_state
    return info

def check_match(user1, user2):
    match_score = {}    
    first_info = edu_info(user1)
    dict = edu_info(user2)
    for item in dict:
        cities = dict[item]['cities']
        #user2 = item
        #print cities
        for city in cities:
            if city in first_info['jmitchel3']['cities']:
                match_score['user'] = 'jmitchel3'
                match_score['user2'] = str(user2.user.username)
                match_score['city'] = city
                print "here! " + str(city)
            else:
                print "not here! " + str(city)

    return match_score




check_match(j,t)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

Start with a function that collects information about a single user, and returns a single dictionary for that user:

```
def edu_info(user1):
    user_1_cities = []
    user_1_schools = []
    user_1_state = []
    first_one = Education.objects.filter(owner=user1)
    for i in first_one:
        user_1_cities.append(str(i.city))
        user_1_schools.append(str(i.school))
        user_1_state.append(str(i.state))
    info = {}
    info['cities'] = user_1_cities
    info['schools'] = user_1_schools
    info['states'] = user_1_state
    return info
```

Then, have a separate function that calls your information collecting function once for each of two users, and computing the number of points with that information.

```
def check_match(user_1, user_2)
    info_1 = edu_info(user_1)
    info_2 = edu_info(user_2)
    school_points = similarity_points(info_1["schools"], info_2["schools"], 10)
    city_points = similarity_points(info_1["cities"], info_2["cities"], 5)
    state_points = similarity_points(info_1["states"], info_2["states"], 2)
    return school_points + city_points + state_points
```

The meat of the `check_match` function is offloaded into it's own helper function. This function finds the intersection of two lists of attributes, and multiplies the number of shared attributes by some point value. It does this by converting the attribute lists to sets and then using the [set intersection operator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection).

So, `similarity_points(["MN","OR","PA", "NJ"],["AZ","NJ","PA"], 2)` would find two matches (NJ and PA) and thus return 4.

```
def similarity_points(attr_1, attr_2, points)
    """Award a number of points for each shared attribute.

    attr_1 and attr_2 should be lists to compare. 
    """
    number_shared = len(set(attr_1) & set(attr_2))
    return number_shared * points
```

Then, you can call the above code like:

```
wilduck_jmitchel3_points = check_match("Wilduck", "jmitchel3")
```

Comment: Dude! That's awesome. Thanks for your help! (also good to know I was sort of on the right track!)

Comment: Wilduck, is there a way to iterate through all fields in the django model and assign to dictionary? So something like `user_1_schools.append(str(i.major))` would be added to the mix without me hard coding it? Or would that not make sense because I have to assign point values too?

Comment: @jmitchel3 I'm not super familiar with Django, but you might be able to do something with the `values` method on your QuerySet see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values . In this case though, if you don't have too many fields, it might be clearer to do it by hand.